# redirect to facebook canvas using fb_graph

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I have an application built with rails gem fb_graph, everything's fine until the moment I integrated it with facebook canvas, at the first try when the app asks for the permissions and the user granted it, it redirects outside the canvas, I mean, the actual url where it's located the app, however when you already gave the perms it loads inside the canvas.

Why is this happening? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide code that you use to login and auth, but I guess you set `redirect_uri` in auth dialog to the direct URL to your app. If you want it to redirect to your canvas, change `redirect_uri` to something like that: `https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP_NAMESPACE`. You can find more info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/).

**edit:** lol, I found this question in related questions section and didn't check the date ^^